# How to make event handler for key down even if form is not visible/closed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm making an app that will control my rgb lights and I want it to handle event for clicking specific key, but i want to run it as a background process.

I have already tried using this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
    }
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F9)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("F9 down");
        }
    }
```

It works, but only if form window is active and visible, so I'm not satisfied. I'm looking for a solution that will work even if the form is invisible.

Answer (score 0):

When a keydown event happens and a form is not focused / active it will not detect the event. However, you can use Win API to create a key listener of sorts. See this link for more details of ["Global Hotkeys"](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/?fbclid=IwAR3A01peTiACveKuKtUrhdkoGsKDafmHjWIdO_50LcaWtlyIb89JB7Il8Fs).